# How to use two controllers method in one form on laravel?

Tags: laravel, forms, controller, routes

I have a productsController and it basicly doing CRUD nicely. But there is a issue. My controller methods getting too long. So I decided to *seperate ImageController and Image table from products*. Because the images need to has on CRUD.

However, the form which is uploading this items is the same with uploading images. So, what is the best practice to make two controller from one form? Also what should be the route look like ?

---

Note: This is a general question. Also code is too long. That's why I didn't add the code here.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very broad question, but it seems like you need to set up a relationship between Product and Image models (assuming you are using models with the controllers you mentioned in your question), so that a Product hasOne Image. Then when you save a Product, you can call the store Image method on the Image like this:

$product->image->storeImage($img);

Where $img is the image file you are uploading. The relationship would look like this:

Products.php:

```
public function image()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Image');
}
```

Image.php:

```
public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
}
```

This is not an exhaustive answer, but hopefully gets you started in the correct path. Of course, you will still need to add other code like the custom "store" function on the Image model, and make sure that you have the correct migrations in place (article_id on the Image model, image_id on the Product model), but this would be one way to separate the code and make your controller lighter. Here is a sample of what you would do in the Image.php model to store an image:

```
class Image extends Model {

    public function storeImage($img){
        //code goes here to store image
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I did the relationship but dont should I call the other controllers method? I mean how this methods controller knows it called? I called from route and form the ProductsController@store method but what about the imagesController@store ?

Comment: The problem is that you are using a controller to handle what should be handled directly in the model. You can certainly accomplish what you're trying to do with controllers, but you aren't able to directly call methods across controllers the way you want to. That's why a relationship between MODELS is necessary. Once the relationship exists, you can call methods from the other model directly, without having to use ajax or some other system of allowing the controllers to talk to each other.

Comment: To clarify, the "store" method will be in the image model, not in the imageController. I have edited my answer to show this.

Comment: just wanna make it clear. Correct me if I am wrong. Normally I have product with image. Than I decided to seperate both database and controllers. So, I created a Image model, create_image_table and imageController. The only thing that I should do is making relationship and call the "$product->relationshipname->store()" that's it ?

Comment: Yes, but you would both need to pass the $image path to the Image model in order to be able to store the image, and you would have to define the storeImage() function on the Image model, as I have shown above. It's difficult to address these types of specifics without seeing your code, but doing my best to help!